# Android Studio doesnt recognize my device - LG Spirit 4G

Tags: android, device

I have developer options enabled, the driver is updated(says the OS win10), and I followed the instructions of the documentation. My manifest :

```
  <application
    android:debuggable="true" //this line says it shouldnt be harcoded?
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_piano"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

And the build graddle file:

```
     android {
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
    repositories {
    jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    } 
  }

  allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
 }

 task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
 android {
    buildTypes {
       debug {
        debuggable true
       }
```

Both manifest and build code copied from the documentation. But it fails to build.graddle. It says: expectin '}' found "
I dont know what is this suposed to mean, since i've done everything the documentation says. I've serached all the answers here in SO but haven't any that worked...Any ideias? 
The link: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html

Comment: is that the whole `build.gradle` file? if it is, then that is your problem

Comment: no, of course not, it's just the line from the documentation, I'll edit the post

Comment: you should also link what documentation you are referring to

Comment: its a syntax error. you need to balance your `{` brackets

Comment: with th brackets balanced now it says can't find "android method()for builds..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have messed up your build.gradle, it should look like this:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    buildscript {
         repositories {
              jcenter()
         }

         dependencies {
             classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

             // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
             // in the individual module build.gradle files
         } 
  }

  allprojects {
       repositories {
           jcenter()
       }
  }

 task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

Note that this is your *top level* build.gradle, it will sit in the root directory of your project. There should **another** build.gradle inside of a folder likely called `/app` this is the file where you add and amend the `android{}` gradle clojure

Comment: Ok, the graddle is running, but when I press "play" the only thing I see is the emulator...No real device at all

Comment: on your device, is usb debugging enabled? https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20enable%20usb%20debugging